# SpringBatch itemReader use to much memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm reading from a database, it has many rows, yes, but "I suppose that the reader frees memory during the step". It takes more than 1Gb of memory. How could improve it? using another kind of reader?

```
...
<bean id="database1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="name" value="bd1" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <property name="sql" value="select image from info where image like '%/Images/%' or image like '%/temp/%'" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="foo.ImagesRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<batch:step id="1Step" next="2Step">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="database1" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="20"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
...
```

RowMapper

```
public class ImagesRowMapper implements RowMapper<String> {

    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getString("image");
    }

}
```

procesor

```
@Override
public String process(String item) throws Exception {
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("process. processing {}", item);
    }
    if (item == ""){
        return null;
    }
    return relativePath(item); //relativePath only change the string an return it
}
```

writer
doesn't do anything is commented
[image: visualVM]

Comment: This is strange; we tried with a lot of rows but without problems. maybe a db-driver issue?

Comment: I'm using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: If memory isn't freed something is holding on to the objects. Can you post some of your code (`RowMapper`, `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter`). Ofcourse it could also be a JDBC driver issue (as mentioned by @bellabax), you could try tuning fetch-size etc.

Comment: added. how can I identify if it is a JDBC issue? it works well with other things

Comment: It might be the size of each item, is it ok with commit-interval much smaller?

Comment: Have you done any profiling with regards to what objects are taking up the memory?  Most good profiling tools will help point out memory leaks (which looks like what you may have).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage spring batch parallel processing :

You can define a taskExecutor

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
```

Use this taskexecutor in your tasklet

```
 <batch:tasklet ref="whatever_your_tasklet_name" transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
```

Spring docs: [Scalability](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html)

Comment: Its a copy past error. kindly ignore what I wanted to show was how you can then refer to task executor using the attribute "task-executor"